# What does it mean when the word “notice” is used after a period of time?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I have problem understanding the exact meaning of phrases like the following examples in which the word ***notice*** is used after a period of time (e.g. month, week or 10 day) appended with a ***apostrophe or apostrophe + s***.

> at least two **weeks’ notice** shall be given
>
> at a **moment's notice**

Does it mean "a notice before the given period of time?"

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/notice: something is announced to happen after the stated time, e.g. a job contract will be terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*'Notice'* has many meanings. In this context, as per [Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/notice),

> A notification by one of the parties to an agreement, as for employment, that the agreement will terminate on a specified date.

Generally "xxxxxx's notice" means saying in advance about a particular time frame, by which/ within which something should be done.
For Example,

> at least two week's notice shall be given,

means that a prior notification will be given with a time frame of 2 weeks to complete a task.